Does the Greek text for Mark 15:33 contain an example of genitive absolute whose action occurs before the action of the main verb?
The Greek text of Mark 15:33 reads:

Καὶ γενομένης ὥρας ἕκτης, σκότος ἐγένετο ἐφ’ ὅλην τὴν γῆν ἕως ὥρας ἐνάτης.

The English translation (KJV) of Mark 15:33 reads:

And when the sixth hour was come, there was darkness over the whole land until the ninth hour.

In the Greek text, "γενομένης ὥρας ἕκτης" is a genitive absolute (with γενομένης being a participle in the aorist tense), and "ἐγένετο" is the main verb.
When a genitive absolute uses an aorist participle, this typically means that the action of the genitive absolute occurs prior to the action of the main verb.
In the case of the Greek text for Mark 15:33, is it fair to say that the action of "γενομένης ὥρας ἕκτης" occurs prior to the action of "ἐγένετο" (i.e., the sixth hour first started, and then the start of darkness happened sometime thereafter)? Thanks for the help!

The Englishman's Greek New Testament renders Mark 15:33 as and being come hour sixth darkness came over all the land until hour ninth. Biblehub states that both verbs (the participle and the indicative) are aorist middle. The evidence is that the actions are concurrent. As soon as the hour arrived, darkness fell.

Your analysis of Mark 15:33 regarding the genitive absolute construction and its temporal sequence is correct. Let's break it down:

Genitive Absolute in Mark 15:33:

The phrase γενομένης ὥρας ἕκτης is indeed a genitive absolute, with γενομένης (aorist participle of γίνομαι) and ὥρας ἕκτης (genitive noun phrase for "sixth hour").
In Greek grammar, the aorist participle in a genitive absolute generally indicates an action that is completed prior to the action of the main verb, unless context or idiom suggests otherwise.


Main Verb in Mark 15:33:

The main verb ἐγένετο ("there was" or "it occurred") describes the onset of darkness.


Temporal Sequence:

Following standard syntax, γενομένης ὥρας ἕκτης would indicate that the sixth hour had come (was completed) before the darkness ἐγένετο began.



Thus, the phrasing suggests that the sixth hour arrived, and then the darkness began.
Comparison with BGT 1 Esdras 8:61 (LXX)
The phrase καὶ γενομένης αὐτόθι ἡμέρας τρίτης from 1 Esdras 8:61 is structurally parallel to the construction in Mark 15:33:

γενομένης: Aorist participle of γίνομαι (indicating the occurrence of the third day).
Main verb: σταθὲν: Aorist passive participle of ἵστημι (indicating "was set").
Here, the third day γενομένης (arrived) before the action described by the main verb (the delivery of the silver and gold to the house of the Lord).

This reinforces the pattern that the genitive absolute with an aorist participle usually indicates an action completed prior to the action of the main clause.
Conclusion
Both Mark 15:33 and 1 Esdras 8:61 demonstrate that in genitive absolutes with an aorist participle, the participial action typically precedes the main verb's action. Therefore, in Mark 15:33, it is fair to conclude that the sixth hour came first, and then the darkness began.

The Englishman's Greek New Testament renders Mark 15:33 as :

and being come hour sixth darkness came over all the land until hour ninth.

Biblehub states that both verbs (the participle and the indicative) are aorist middle.
The evidence is that the actions are concurrent.
As soon as the hour arrived, darkness fell.

I would challenge the assertion that in Mark 15:33, γενομένης acts adverbially to ἐγένετο - I do not believe that ἐγένετο is modified at all.  Indeed, both are the same verb!
The simplest way to see this verse is as two almost-separate clauses which I would translate (overly literally) as follows:

And having become of [the] sixth hour, darkness came over all the land
until [the] ninth hour.

Typical of Mark, this is a rather uncomplicated construction - short and to the point.
